# coc.nvim - no rome found in your project root

Tags: linux-ubuntu, plugin-coc

I have the latest version of Ubuntu and recently installed vim. I'm trying to get coc.nvim to work. See https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim . This is an autocompletion package (and then some) for vim and nvim.

I installed the package but when I execute

`:CocInstall coc-rome`

to get specific settings for JavaScript, I get this error:

`[coc.nvim] No rome found  in your project root.`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install https://github.com/rome/tools with npm/yarn. `coc-rome` will try to resolve `rome` from:

1. `rome.bin` in `coc-settings.json`
2. `$PATH`
3. project local node_modules